# Remote Desktop to Amazon EC2 Instance

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2

So I just purchased a Windows Server Micro Reserved instance on Amazon EC2. Though now I don't know how to work with it. What DNS does it have, how can I use Remote Desktop to get into it, etc etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read EC2 Documentation [Connect to Your Windows Instance](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/GettingStartedGuide/).

Look Public DNS in https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/:

[image]

Comment: I bought a Reserved Instance which is listed as active. Do I need to create an instance to the reserved instance?

Comment: No, your instance is already running and will be shown in the AWS Console as illustrated in ooshro's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to right click on the instance and choose get windows password. Then, use your key pair to decrypt the password. Make a note of the password. Ensure that in your security group, port 3389 is open to all connections (0.0.0.0).

You can connect using RDP then using administrator account and your decrypted password. The server name will be the public DNS name of your instance.